# Can the "angry customer" event be skipped without paying or taking the rep hit?

Tags: motor-world-car-factory

In Motor World, there is an event where an angry customer had his engine blown.

> **Angry Customer**
>
> This one is very upset...
> A customer has written mail directly to you. His car's engine has blown up one week after he purchased it. Your dealer has refused to take this under his warranty. What will you do ?
>
> - Ignore him. *(Tactic fail, down Demand, down Image)*
> - Fix the engine at the factory: 5 Donut *(Variable)*
> - Get him a new car: 3 Cash *(Tactic Win)*

Happens that the event pops when I am short on donuts, and paying cash is out of question.

Is there some way to avoid this event once it happens (short of hacking the game APK or memory data) so I don't need to either pay or take the rep hit?

Comment: We are not here to help you hack a game. See : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Karlyr, they did not ask how to hack the game, they specifically asked if there was a way to accomplish this *without* hacking.

Comment: Oh my bad. Read diagonally it seems like.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Motor World Wikia page on Events](http://motorworld.wikia.com/wiki/Event):

> Events are random occurrences that pop up during play.

Angry Customer is on this page. As it is random, there is no way to avoid the event.

---

**POST EDIT:**

It seems like you will have to handle this event. Unfortunately, this is one of the random events with no easy option, especially if you are low on donuts and/or cash.

Comment: avoid the event after it popped up. sorry for not being clear, but I am not concerned about not having it happen.